# Remove categoies, tagging and authors functionality from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

How do you remove the tagging and authors functionality from wordpress.

This is so it does not appear in the backend for users, it would remove the categories panel from the post page and all the other flim-flam.

I would assume that wordpress's default post is a special kind of custom post type that can be modified, and therefore could have it's functionality disabled.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links to articles online.  Some require some manipulation to accomplish hiding the specific menus you are looking to remove.

http://hungred.com/how-to/remove-wordpress-admin-menu-affecting-wordpress-core-system/
http://barunsingh.com/software/custom-admin-menu/ (a plugin, probably the easiest way)
http://www.strangework.com/2010/03/24/how-to-hide-an-admin-menu-in-wordpress/
http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2010/04/29/how-to-hide-menus-in-wordpress/